# Can't login after removing Flatpak

Tags: login, 19.04, flatpak

I had installed flatpak to run an application. Since it didn't quite work, I removed it using the following command:

```
sudo apt remove flatpak
```

On restart, I'm getting the error below. There is an OK button, but I can't hit it and can't even get to the desktop. The mouse isn't working and neither is the keyboard.

I am running Ubuntu 19.04. Here is the error:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:

/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh: line25: flatpak: command not found

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. 
You should fix the problem as soon as feasibile.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this situation you have to remove or comment out that line in your profile file the steps are:

1. Switch to the login console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, then
2. Locate that file and remove that line that is causing the boot issue:

   ```
   sudo sed -i.bak '25d' /etc/profile
   ```
3. Remove any remnants

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
   sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/Xsession.d/20flatpak
   ```
4. Reboot the system

Comment: Thanks this helped me in to console mode, since the GUI was not loading at all. I couldnt even get to the login screen. I had to purge as @Norbert0 suggested above.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to remove it again by purging

```
sudo apt-get purge flatpak
```

or remove its [leftovers](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/amd64/flatpak/filelist) with

```
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/20flatpak
```

and then reboot.